# Mage::registry() doesn't carry between methods

Tags: magento

Mage::registry doesn't hold between methods.  Thoughts? (Yes, displayOrder is called first).

```
public function displayOrderAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $post        = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $block       = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('returner.displayorder');
    $returnOrder = Mage::getModel('returner/order')->getOrder($post['increment_id'], $post['email']);
    Mage::register( 'returnOrder', $returnOrder );
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function verifyItemsAction()
{
    $post  = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $order = Mage::registry('returnOrder');
}
```

Comment: To my knowledge Mage::registry() is a global variables that only pass information within that page. Since 'verifyItems' is a new page been generate it should not carry through.. You may want to use session instead

Comment: I'm going to add my previous comment as an answer below, so that others don't see it as been unanswered and spend time trying to answer it, so please accept it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge Mage::registry() is a global variables that only pass information within that page. Since 'verifyItems' is a new page been generate it should not carry through.. You may want to use session instead